# Maximum size of enviornment/path variable in unix

Tags: unix

I am working on a requirement where I am assigning multiple paths to environment variable in unix for searching in different directories.
as below.

export TB_SCC= .:/users/e649744/WTEST/AB:/users/e649744/WTEST/BC:/users/e649744/WTEST/CD:/users/e649744/WTEST/BC:/users/e649744/WTEST/DE:/users/e649744/WTEST/EF:/users/e649744/WTEST/FG:/users/e649744/WTEST/GH:/users/e649744/WTEST/HI:/users/e649744/WTEST/JK:/users/e649744/WTEST/LM

So is there a size limit/restriction for environment variable in unix?
IS there a fixed limit after which it will not accept the value?

Please help.

Comment: Don't have any background for this, but I say no. Used way longer environment variable strings and worked without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try [getconf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getconf.html):

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX
```

> ARG_MAX: Maximum length, in bytes, of the arguments for one of the exec subroutines, including environment data.

On my machine this currently yields 2MB, probably more than enough for most cases:

```
2097152
```

See also: [getconf Command](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.cmds%2Fdoc%2Faixcmds2%2Fgetconf.htm)